# Stripe Payments for a delivery company

Tags: php, api, data-structures, stripe-payments

I'm setting up Stripe for a service based company. They pickup and deliver an item from a customers location to a chosen destination. Basically a courier service.

For the API, I am creating a Customer object, then adding a Card object to that customer, then applying a Charge object to that card.

However, I also need a way of storing the details of the Order, (pickup location, delivery location, type of item, weight, dates etc.)

As they don't sell 'Products' as such, can I just attach all this info to an Order object, or am I required to create a Product object?

If I create a Product, do I then also have to create an SKU for the specific delivery task? Some clarification on how to structure a non physical/digital service is required, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orders](https://stripe.com/docs/api#order_object), [products](https://stripe.com/docs/api#product_object) and [SKUs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#skus) are all part of [Relay](https://stripe.com/docs/relay), which is a somewhat distinct part of Stripe's API meant to enable sellers to sell their products on third-party platforms such as Twitter, SPRING, etc.

In your case, you probably want to simply [create one-off charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) and not use orders at all. You can use the charge's [`description`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-description) and [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) to store arbitrary information related to the charge.